# TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined while writing unit test with axios

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, axios, enzyme

I am writing unit tests for a component. My component has a method which is using axios. I want to write unit tests for it. 
Here is how I have written and I am getting an error.

```
import axios from "axios";
jest.mock('axios');
jest.mock('axios', () => ({ get: jest.fn(),post: jest.fn(), create: jest.fn() }));
test("on search it should call get store", () => {
    axios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(data));
    const wrapper = shallow(<ComponentA />);
    const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), "getStores");
    wrapper.setState({
      searchText: "test1"
    });
    wrapper.instance().onSearchClick();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("test1");
  });
```

here is the method

```
getStores = term => {
    const uri = URI("")
      .path("/api/link")
      .addQuery({term: term})
      .toString();
    return axios.get(uri)
      .then(response => {
        const storeResponse = response.data;
          return storeResponse;
            } catch (error) {}
            this.props.onStoreFetch(stores, false);
          } else {
            this.props.onStoreFetch([], true);
          }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.props.onStoreFetch([], true);
      });
  };
```

Error I am getting is

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Answer (score 5):

Here is a working example:

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class SetStoreOverlay extends Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchText: '',
    };
  }
  getStores = (term) => {
    const uri = `/searchux/api/v1/storeProxy?term=${term}`;

    return axios
      .get(uri)
      .then((response) => console.log(response))
      .catch((error) => {
        this.props.onStoreFetch([], true);
      });
  };

  onSearchClick = () => {
    return this.getStores(this.state.searchText);
  };

  render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}

export default SetStoreOverlay;
```

`index.spec.tsx`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SetStoreOverlay from './';
import axios from 'axios';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

jest.mock('axios', () => {
  return {
    get: jest.fn(),
  };
});

describe('SetStoreOverlay', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const data = {};
    (axios.get as jest.Mocked<any>).mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(data));
    const mProps = { onStoreFetch: jest.fn() };
    const wrapper = shallow(<SetStoreOverlay {...mProps} />);
    const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance() as any, 'getStores');
    wrapper.setState({ searchText: 'test1' });
    wrapper.instance()['onSearchClick']();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test1');
    expect(axios.get).toBeCalledWith(`/searchux/api/v1/storeProxy?term=test1`);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59317049/index.spec.tsx (14.204s)
  SetStoreOverlay
    ✓ should pass (27ms)

  console.log src/stackoverflow/59317049/index.tsx:1599
    {}

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |    94.12 |      100 |    85.71 |    93.75 |                   |
 index.tsx |    94.12 |      100 |    85.71 |    93.75 |                18 |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        16.23s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59317049

Comment: One thing that I forgot to mention here is that I am not using axios as it is. I have a file I import axios there and then create an instance and then use that instance everywhere. In that case it says     TypeError: _axios.default.create is not a function

Comment: Why do you need to call `jest.mock('axios')` with a second argument to define `get`? I found it didn't work unless I did the same thing, but I don't understand why because I'm able to call `axios.get` in the file I'm testing...

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comment that you are using an imported instance of axios, it looks like you should be mocking the instance or helper that you imported, instead of mocking axios itself. I don't know what your project structure is, but I put a simple example below. Assuming that you created your helper in a file called **helper/api.js**, you should create your mock helper in a file called **helper/__mocks__/api.js** and use **jest.mock()** to mock the helper in your test file. Your tests should then use your mock helper wherever axios is called.

```
src/
    App.js
    App.test.js
    helpers/
            api.js
            __mocks__/
                        api.js
```

`helpers/api.js`:

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://my-base-url",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
  }
});
```

`helpers/__mocks__/api.js`:

```
export default {
  get: jest.fn(() =>
    Promise.resolve({
      data: [{key1: "value1", key2: "value2"}]
    })
  )
};
```

`src/App.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import api from "./helpers/api";
.
.
.
.
componentDidMount() {
    api
        .get('my-path/')
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                //update state
            })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            //do error handling
        });
}
```

`src/App.test.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import App from "./App";

jest.mock("./helpers/api");
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using `@ngneat/until-destroy` package (and angular).

I'm using `@ngneat/until-destroy` package and that he crashes all tests. After downgrading it to 7.x.x version all tests with @UntilDestroy decorator was crashed. If you use it, try to upgrade it to 8.x.x (but pay attention. @ngneat/until-destroy 8.x.x support angular 10.0.5+ only :D)